# C# inserting data into excel using OleDbConnection but the data is on the wrong row

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

I have an excel workbook with 27 different worksheets, 24 of these worksheets are populated from just 3 of them and I am trying to insert the necessary data into the 3 worksheets.

The problem I'm running into is that on two of the worksheets (HeaderExport and MarkupExport) the data is getting inserted just below the row where it needs to, and all the other worksheets can't read it. How can I insert the data starting on the correct row?

Also on the third worksheet (EstimateExportData) I cant get any data to insert anywhere on the worksheet. I've double checked the spelling of the worksheet name and its correct. I've tried it with a string and a number, in excel the column is general. No errors are thrown

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

```
 private void radExportToPivot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //where the excel template file is stored
            string sourcePath = @"C:\TEMP\METExport.xlsx";
            string targetPath;
            //ask the user where they want to save it to
            RadSaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new RadSaveFileDialog();
            DialogResult dr = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                targetPath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!targetPath.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            {
                targetPath = targetPath + ".xlsx";
            }
            ;
            //copy the file where the user said
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath, true);
            //set connection string 
            string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                                    "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0'", targetPath);
            //populate file with all necessary data
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();
                HeaderExport(cn);
                EstimateExport(cn);
                MarkUpExport(cn);
                cn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void MarkUpExport(OleDbConnection cn)
        {
            _entity.EstimateOverheads.Where(x => x.EstID == Est.EstID).Load();
            var estOverHeads = _entity.EstimateOverheads.Local.ToBindingList();
            _entity.Estimates.Where(x=>x.EstID == Est.EstID).Load();
            var estimate = _entity.Estimates.Local.ToBindingList().First();

            foreach (var overhead in estOverHeads)
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO [MarkUpExport$]" +
                    "(LineItemType, FeeName, funding, Profit, Contingency, CommAdder, " +
                    "HomeField, ga, LaborBurden, OfficeOverhead, FieldOverhead, SubAdmin)" +
                    "VALUES(@LineItemType, @FeeName, @funding, @Profit, @Contingency, @CommAdder, " +
                    "@HomeField, @ga, @LaborBurden, @OfficeOverhead, @FieldOverhead, @SubAdmin)", cn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineItemType", overhead.LineItemType.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeeName", overhead.FeeName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@funding", estimate.funding);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Profit", overhead.Profit);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contingency", overhead.Contingency);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommAdder", overhead.CommAdder);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeField", overhead.HomeField);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ga", overhead.ga);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LaborBurden", overhead.LaborBurden);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeOverhead", overhead.OfficeOverhead);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldOverhead", overhead.FieldOverhead);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubAdmin", overhead.SubAdmin);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        private void EstimateExport(OleDbConnection cn)
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                "INSERT INTO [EstimateExportData$]" +
                "(RevenueType)" +
                "VALUES(@RevenueType)", cn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RevenueType", 1);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private void HeaderExport(OleDbConnection cn)
        {
            Data.Estimate estimate = LoadDataforExport();

                OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO [HeaderExport$] " +
                                "(Project, SubEstimate, Description, funding, MarketSector, " +
                                "ProjectManager, ProjectSpecialist, ClientCode, ClientClass, " +
                                //"Currency, " +
                                "ClientName, ContractNumber, StartDate" +
                                ", FinishDate, Merrick_is_Sub, MarketSegment, ServiceBusinessUnit, ServiceLine, " +
                                "WorkLocation, DamagesProtection, InternationalCode, ContractForm, LEEDLevel, OrigDate, AcctManager," +
                                " FeeType, process_step, ContractValue, tm_comp, Company, Organization, BudgetLevel, " +
                                "ChargeableProject, ClientAddress, ClientCity, ClientState, ClientZip, ClientCountry, ClientContact," +
                                " ClientPhone, ClientFax, ClientEmail, APContact, APPhone, APFax, APEmail, ClientContractNumber, " +
                                "EndClient, OverallFee, WorkType, CompanyRole, WorkCity, WorkState, WorkCountry, WorkZip, " +
                                "Opportunity, NAICS, CertCurrentCost, LimitLiability, GHVTTax, GrossReceiptsTax, CAS, " +
                                "IncurredCostFAR, GSAContract, " +
                                "SBAPlan, " +
                                "DateCreated, " +
                                "CreatedBy, DateModified, ModifiedBy, Location, PayrollDate, RateSheet" +
                                ") " +
                        "VALUES(" +
                                "@Project, @SubEstimate, @Description, @funding, @MarketSector, " +
                                "@ProjectManager, @ProjectSpecialist, @ClientCode, @ClientClass, " +
                                //"@Currency, " +
                                "@ClientName, @ContractNumber, @StartDate" +
                                ", @FinishDate, @Merrick_is_Sub, @MarketSegment, @ServiceBusinessUnit, @ServiceLine, " +
                                "@WorkLocation, @DamagesProtection, @InternationalCode, @ContractForm, @LEEDLevel, @OrigDate, @AcctManager," +
                                " @FeeTyp, @process_stepe, @ContractValue, @tm_comp, @Company, @Organization, @BudgetLevel, " +
                                "@ChargeableProject, @ClientAddress, @ClientCity, @ClientState, @ClientZip, @ClientCountry, @ClientContact," +
                                " @ClientPhone, @ClientFax, @ClientEmail, @APContact, @APPhone, @APFax, @APEmail, @ClientContractNumber, " +
                                "@EndClient, @OverallFee, @WorkType, @CompanyRole, @WorkCity, @WorkState, @WorkCountry, @WorkZip, " +
                                "@Opportunity, @NAICS, @CertCurrentCost, @LimitLiability, @GHVTTax, @GrossReceiptsTax, @CAS, " +
                                "@IncurredCostFAR, @GSAContract, " +
                                "@SBAPlan, " +
                                "@DateCreated," +
                                "@CreatedBy, @DateModified, @ModifiedBy, @Location, @PayrollDate, @RateSheet" +
                                ")", cn);

                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project", estimate.Project ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubEstimate", estimate.SubEstimate ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", estimate.Description ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@funding", estimate.funding ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarketSector", estimate.MarketSector ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectManager", estimate.ProjectManager ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectSpecialist", estimate.ProjectSpecialist ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientCode", estimate.ClientCode ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientClass", estimate.ClientClass ?? "");
                //cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", estimate.Currency ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName", estimate.ClientName ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractNumber", estimate.ContractNumber ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", estimate.StartDate ?? DateTime.MinValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishDate", estimate.FinishDate ?? DateTime.MinValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Merrick_is_Sub", estimate.Merrick_is_Sub.ToString() ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarketSegment", estimate.MarketSegment ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceBusinessUnit", estimate.ServiceBusinessUnit ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceLine", estimate.ServiceLine ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkLocation", estimate.WorkLocation ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DamagesProtection", estimate.DamagesProtection ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternationalCode", estimate.InternationalCode ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractForm", estimate.ContractForm ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LEEDLevel", estimate.LEEDLevel ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrigDate", estimate.OrigDate ?? DateTime.MinValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcctManager", estimate.AcctManager ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeeType", estimate.FeeType ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_step", estimate.process_step.ToString() ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractValue", estimate.ContractValue.ToString() ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tm_comp", estimate.tm_comp.ToString() ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", estimate.Company ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Organization", estimate.Organization ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BudgetLevel", estimate.BudgetLevel ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChargeableProject", estimate.ChargeableProject.ToString() ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientAddress", estimate.ClientAddress ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientCity", estimate.ClientCity ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientState", estimate.ClientState ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientZip", estimate.ClientZip ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientCountry", estimate.ClientCountry ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientContact", estimate.ClientContact ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientPhone", estimate.ClientPhone ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientFax", estimate.ClientFax ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientEmail", estimate.ClientEmail ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APContact", estimate.APContact ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APPhone", estimate.APPhone ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APFax", estimate.APFax ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APEmail", estimate.APEmail ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientContractNumber", estimate.ClientContractNumber ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndClient", estimate.EndClient ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OverallFee", estimate.OverallFee ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkType", estimate.WorkType ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyRole", estimate.CompanyRole ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkCity", estimate.WorkCity ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkState", estimate.WorkState ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkCountry", estimate.WorkCountry ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkZip", estimate.WorkZip ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opportunity", estimate.Opportunity ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAICS", estimate.NAICS ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CertCurrentCost", estimate.CertCurrentCost ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LimitLiability", estimate.LimitLiability ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GHVTTax", estimate.GHVTTax ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrossReceiptsTax", estimate.GrossReceiptsTax ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAS", estimate.CAS ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncurredCostFAR", estimate.IncurredCostFAR ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GSAContract", estimate.GSAContract ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SBAPlan", estimate.SBAPlan ?? "");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCreated", estimate.DateCreated ?? DateTime.MinValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", estimate.CreatedBy);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateModified", estimate.DateModified ?? DateTime.MinValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedBy", estimate.ModifiedBy);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", estimate.Location);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollDate", estimate.PayrollDate ?? DateTime.MinValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RateSheet", estimate.CurrencyRate.ToString());

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: your config says `HDR=YES`. So, if you target row index 1, it will insert into 2. Hence, 1 below where you want

Comment: [Side-note] I recently worked on a project where I also used OleDbConnection. Ran into all sorts of trouble with 32/64bit stuff. Ended up replacing it with EPPlus which was a lot easier to work with in my case. That of course doesn't answer your question, just sharing my experience.

Comment: Also, my first comment might be irrelevant because I don't see you inserting anything into specific position. Hence, your ordering is probably up to Excel application itself. Especially that you're working with `.xlsx`, not `csv`. So, what you see is how Excel ordering data.